# Is there any difference between "bring something" and "bring something by"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *brings something* and *bring something by*? In the 24th episode of the 8th season of *The Office*, Dwight used *bring by*, which was the first time I hear the phrasal verb used. Here is the context:

> Dwight: Hey everybody, just a few hours left for the free family portrait studio. Darryl. We’d love to see little Jada come by. Angela? Why don’t you **bring by** your little angel?

Would the meaning of the sentence change if Dwight just used *bring*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In expressions such as 'drop by', 'come by', 'bring someone by', etc, the word 'by' means 'here', or 'to my home'. It is mainly informal or conversational American English, and can usually be omitted without any change of meaning.

> come by
>
> PHRASAL VERB 1 North American Call casually and briefly as a visitor.
>
> ‘his friends came by’

[Come by (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/come_by)

Comment: I find it perfectly normal in British English as well.

Comment: @ColinFine - yes, it has percolated into BrE, but it still has a slightly American flavour for me, and, it seems, Lexico (Oxford).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Michael's answer, you also might say

> bring **over** (to) = *bring them from one place to someone else's place*

> bring **along** = *bring them with you*